# Parsing the Azure BatchClient Transcription results

Tags: c#, json, linq, azure

I have created an application that will run the batch transcription service on azure successfully.  The response comes back in a json format, which has been deserialized into an object that I need to get to.  Here is the object (this was pulled from a Microsoft sample and not tampered with):

```
    namespace BatchClient
{
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class AudioFileResult
    {
        public string AudioFileName { get; set; }
        public List<SegmentResult> SegmentResults { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<AudioFileResult> AudioFileResults { get; set; }
    }

    public class NBest
    {
        public double Confidence { get; set; }
        public string Lexical { get; set; }
        public string ITN { get; set; }
        public string MaskedITN { get; set; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
    }

    public class SegmentResult
    {
        public string RecognitionStatus { get; set; }
        public string Offset { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public List<NBest> NBest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This gets deserialzed like this:

```
var resultObject0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(results0);
```

Now the code I am currently using to loop through this is using a series of Foreach loops like this:

```
foreach(var x in resultObject0.AudioFileResults)
                            {
                                foreach(var y in x.SegmentResults)
                                {
                                    foreach(var z in y.NBest)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(z.Display);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

This works, and seems to work quickly, but it seems messy.  Is there a better way to do this, perhaps through LINQ?

Thanks.

Comment: *This works, and seems to work quickly, but it seems messy* What don't you like about it? Is there something you're trying to do differently with the results? Perhaps you could serialize it into a dynamic if you didn't want static classes

Comment: Seems odd to use the nested for loops like this.  I could look at moving it to a dynamic and see if that gets me anything. Perhaps there is a linq equivalent out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample example for converting Foreach to Linq call:

**Foreach loop**

```
 var participantList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var community in communities)
        {
            foreach (var tournament in community.Tournaments)
            {
                foreach (var round in tournament.Rounds)
                {
                    foreach (var match in round.Matches)
                    {
                        if (match.Home.ParticipantId.IsNotNull())
                        {
                           participantList.Add(match.Home.ParticipantId); 
                        }
                        if (match.Away.ParticipantId.IsNotNull())
                        {
                           participantList.Add(match.Away.ParticipantId); 
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

**LINQ**

```
var participantList = communities.SelectMany(c => c.Tournaments)
                                 .SelectMany(t => t.Rounds)
                                 .SelectMany(r => r.Matches)                                
                                 .ToList();
```

Hope this example will help you, let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: This does clean up the code as requested.  Thanks.  Now I need to do some testing to see if the foreach or linq is quicker.  This will be a high use system so each clock tick counts.